# displaying data from DB based on the parameters selected in ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

Is there anyway to retrieve the data from DB, based on the value selected in parameter dropdown.

For example: `if the param1=all,param2=all,param3=all then $F{average_value} 
        if param1=single,param2=all,param3=all then $F{avg_value based on the single value selected}.`

I have written queries to fetch the data based on the value selected but how do we map the value selected in parameter field and the value in DB field.

please help me to design the report according to the above condition.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. For example you can use parameter in query. Or you can use *Java JasperReports API*

Comment: Hi Alex, How do i use the logic in jasper report.could you give some logic